# How to update ssl cert without restarting Ktor server?

Tags: ktor

I'm using SSL configured as in https://ktor.io/docs/ssl.html but can't seem to find a way to handle when certbot renews the cert.

Is there a known/preferred way to automatically renew the cert without restarting the server?

Comment: You can use the `setCertificateEntry` on a `KeyStore` object to replace an existing entry.  The answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889058/programmatically-import-ca-trust-cert-into-existing-keystore-file-without-using may help you.