# Java keystore load works fine on JDK 8 , but throws exception "stream does not represent a PKCS12 key store" on JDK 11

Tags: java, keystore

I am importing certificates in Java Keystore programmatically. I referred [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889058/2458858) for the same.

Essentially from the post, the code works fine when compiled and run on Java 8. But on Java 11, `keystore.load` throws exception:

```
try {
         
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        try (FileInputStream storeInputStream = new FileInputStream(keystorePath);) {

            keystore.load(storeInputStream, storePassword); // storePassword is char[]
            // rest of the stuff
            
    }
```

Exception thrown by `keystore.load`:

> java.io.IOException: stream does not represent a PKCS12 key store     at
> org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.ProvPKCS12$PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown
> Source)   at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)

What could be the issue? I am assuming `.jks` files do not depend on Java version?

Comment: isn't password supposed to be string or char? why is it also FileInputStream?

Comment: @ÇiğdemErşepçiler it is char[] only

Comment: Try taking Bouncy Castle out of the classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It was this line:

`KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());`

Basically `KeyStore.getDefaultType()` returns `jks` in case of Java 8 while it returns `pkcs12` in java 11.

And since my keystore is `jks` type, in java 11 it failed to load when keystore was getting initialised by default to `pkcs12`.

Changing this line to `KeyStore.getInstance("jks")` fixed the issue.